# UPDATE queries successful but affect 0 rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I am new to PostgreSQL (version 9.3) and I have tried to run several UPDATE queries which have returned successfully but which have affected 0 rows.

**Ex 1.** I have two tables cropvalues and crops.  crops contains various cropnames in one column (name) and an associated primary key integer in another column (id).  I want to update an empty column in the cropvalues table (crops_id) - which is a foreign key to crops.id - so that it contains the respective primary key integer for each crop - I have a temporary column in the cropvalues table with the various cropnames (cropname) which I will delete after updating.

```
UPDATE cropvalues
SET crops_id = crops.id
FROM crops
WHERE cropvalues.cropname = crops.name;
```

**Ex 2.** I need to update cells containing null values in various columns.  The following query affects 0 rows when the WHERE statement is included although there are clearly empty cells; when the WHERE statement is removed then the query affects all cells.

```
UPDATE cropvalues
SET time_id = '1'
WHERE time_id IS NULL;
```

I must be missing something simple, but it's so simple that I do not know where to look.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you run your queries as selects to confirm that you are hitting the columns you expect, e.g. SELET * FROM FROM crops
WHERE cropvalues.cropname = crops.name;

Comment: SELECT * FROM crops, cropvalues WHERE cropvalues.cropname = crops.name; returns all the columns from the two tables but no rows ......ah i just caught my mistake, one column had the names capitalized!  Thanks for putting me on the right path Paddy.

Comment: In future, if you're going to ask questions that depend so much on the data in the tables, you need to *show the data and table definitions*. The best way to do that is usually http://sqlfiddle.com/. Anyway, please post an answer to your own question explaining what was wrong for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it was the case sensitivity of PostgreSQL that led to the queries completing successfully but not affecting any rows as one column had the entries capitalized and the other column did not have the entries capitalized.